# Does Lipschitz imply locally surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ a non constant Lipschitzian function with parameter $k<1$, that is: for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2$ one has
$|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x-y|$.
Is $f$ locally surjective that is: for every $a\in f(\mathbb C)$, there exists open sets $U,V$ such that $a\in U$ and $f(a)\in V$ with $f(U)=V$?

Comment: Constant functions are Lipschitz, so...

Comment: Yes. You are right. I forgot to remove these kind of functions. Anyway, I will edit it.

Comment: It's not quite so simple to avoid this "trivial" problem.  If for instance the imaginary part of $f$ is constant, we have the same problem as when $f$ itself were constant (namely, the image of $f$ has empty interior, so there is no hope for $f(U)$ to be open)